# Python py_compile into a specific directory

Tags: python

Is there a way to Compile .py files into a specific directory?
For example i have an pythonscript in /Users/User/test.py and want to compile it into the directory /Users/User/Desktop . Is there a way?

Im using Python 3.6

Answer (score 4):

You can simply provide, absolute or relative path as an argument to compile method in py_compile.

For more info, read up this implementation of compile method
[Here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/502d551c6d782963d26957a9e5ff1588946f233f/Lib/py_compile.py#L72) .

As an example you can start with this:

`import py_compile
py_compile.compile('test.py','/Users/User/Desktop/test.pyc')`

Comment: Thanks, didn't thought of that